# Linq to Entities: If I DON'T want a property called ID what is the attribute I need to use

Tags: linq-to-entities

I am creating a POCO object for ADO.NET DataServce (they are called WCF DataServices now) The compiler tells me that entities need to have an ID property.

OK, that's fine but I don't want to call mine ID, I want to call it 'Code'. What attribute do I put on the property 'Code' to tell the service that it is the 'primary key'?

I have been searching Google for an answer but today I can't seem the guess the right sequence of words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add an attribute on your POCO class that tells ADO Data Services which property is your Unique Key. Like an example below. You mark the property to use with: DataServiceKey("Id")]. In my case it was "Id". But you should be able to change it to somethign else.

```
 [DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string PhoneType { get; set; }
    public int SortOder { get; set; }
}
```

Key property with different name:

```
 [DataServiceKey("Code")]
public class Phone
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string PhoneType { get; set; }
    public int SortOder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I also found the attribute [Key] on the actual property works too.